# MVC- drop down values not binding for all the rows in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, model

The model:

```
public class EdituserModel  : IEnumerable<EdituserModel>
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<EdituserModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<EdituserModel>)editUser).GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<EdituserModel>)editUser).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<table id="tbltbl_usertable" class="tableasd" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:115px;text-align: center; ">User Id</th>
        <th style="width:100px;text-align: center;">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="UserID" style="text-align: center; ">
                <span style="text-align: center;">@user.UserID</span>
            </td>
            <td class="Status" style="text-align: center;">                     
                <select id="SelectedStatusId" name="SelectedStatusId" value="@user.Status" >
                    <option value="A"  selected="selected">Admin</option>
                    <option value="U">Dashboard user</option>
                </select>         
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

From the above code, the `UserID` is being displayed properly (8 rows for 8 users). But only one drop down is being displayed for the first row and not the subsequent rows. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is the model for the View? Since you're looping through `Model`, I'm assuming it is `IEnumerbale<EdituserModel>`. So why is there a `List<EdituserModel>` property inside `EdituserModel`?

Comment: @adiga. Yes it is the EditUserModel. I have removed the list from the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: isn't the model `IEnumerbale<EdituserModel>`? You're looping through `Model`

Comment: @adiga. Yes it is

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that you've inappropriately given each `select` the same `id` - which is not legal HTML?  Try giving them unique `id` attributes and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @stephen.vakil. If Im binding the rows from database and the number of rows change, how can i assign unique ids?

Comment: e.g. `id='@(user.UserID + "selectedStatusID")'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're binding to the `select` is wrong. You can't set an `option` in the dropdown by setting the `value` attribute of `select` ([try it](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJIJMQO1KPQM)). Besides, you're setting `selected="selected"` on the first `option`. I'm guessing that is selected in all the dropdowns.

> *"Only one drop down is being displayed for the first row and not the subsequent rows"*:

I don't know how this is possible. I have tested this in my system and it wasn't reproducible.

So, how to bind your value to the dropdown? You should use MVC's [`DropdownListFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) HTML Helper.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="UserID" style="text-align: center; ">
            <span style="text-align: center;">Model.editUser[i].UserID</span>
        </td>

        <td class="Status" style="text-align: center;">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.editUser[i].Status, new SelectList(new[] {
                new { Text = "Admin", Value = "A" },
                new { Text = "Dashboard user", Value = "U" },
            }, "Value", "Text", Model.editUser[i].Status))
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

You should use a `for` loop instead of foreach whenever you're looping and creating form elements in MVC ([Why though?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)). This generates appropriate `name` attribute which are important when submitting forms.

(We usually get the `SelectListItem`s in a `ViewBag` and bind. But there is an issue in MVC with `DropDownList` helper when we are looping)

*"BUT I DONT CARE ABOUT GIVING PROPER NAMES TO FORM ELEMENTS 
OR DROPDOWNLISTFOR OR ANY OF THAT STUFF. I JUST WANT TO BIND MY DROPDOWN OKAY?"*:

Then:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="UserID" style="text-align: center; ">
            <span style="text-align: center;">@Model.editUser[i].UserID</span>
        </td>

        <td class="Status" style="text-align: center;">
            <select id="SelectedStatusId" name="SelectedStatusId">
                <option value="A" @(Model.editUser[i].Status == "A" ? "selected" : "" )>Admin</option>
                <option value="U" @(Model.editUser[i].Status =="U" ? "selected" : "" )>Dashboard user</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

**UPDATE**: I saw your update now reagarding the `Enumerator`. See, this is why I asked you post all the relevant code. You said your model for the page was `IEnumerable<EdituserModel>`. My asnwer would still work. Replace all the `Model[i]` with `Model.editUser[i]` (otherwise you'd have implement `IList` as well)